# When is the sum of two uniform random variables uniform?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, uniform-distribution

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$, two random variables, are both uniformly distributed over $[0,1]$. Let $Z=\frac{1}{2}X+\frac{1}{2}Y$.

I know that in general, $Z$ is not uniform. For instance, $Z$ is not uniform if $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

On the other hand, if $X=Y$, then $Z$ is uniformly distributed over $[0,1]$.

My question: Suppose $Z$ is uniformly distributed over $[0,1]$. Is $X=Y$? In other words, is $X=Y$ the only case where $Z$ is uniform over $[0,1]$?

Comment: I would make your main question clearer, namely: "If $X,Y,Z$ are random variables, $Z$ is uniformly distributed, and $Z = X + Y$ then must $X$ and $Y$ be uniformly distributed? (both in general and when $Z$ takes values in some compact interval)"

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I think he is talking about the "coupling (?)" between $X$ and $Y$, assuming $X$ and $Y$ are both uniform.

Comment: @FiMePr Exactly!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is YES.

We have $$
\begin{align*}
\frac 1 3 &=E[Z^{2}]
\\ &=\frac  1 4 E[(X+Y)^{2}]\\
 &=\frac  1 4(E[X^{2}]+E[Y^{2}]+2E[XY])\\
 &=\frac   1 4(\frac   1 3+\frac   1 3+2E[XY]).
\end{align*}$$  This gives $E[XY]=\frac   1 3$. This implies that we have equality in Cauchy-Schwarz inequality: $$E[XY]=\sqrt {E[X^{2}]}\sqrt {E[Y^{2}]}$$ and hence $X$ and $Y$ are constant multiples of each other. But  the constant factor has to be $1$ since $X$ and $Y$ have uniform distribution on $[0,1]$. Hence $X=Y$.

Comment: @PeterShor Thanks for pointing out the typo.

Comment: I made two edits that I think help readability -- adding `\begin{align*}...\end{align*}` to your first equation block, and adding brackets around expectations. Please do check that I didn't alter your answer and feel free to revert/undo as you see appropriate.

Comment: @Neal Thanks for editing.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you very much. I didn't expect such an elegant argument. I thought that $X$ and $Y$ can be correlated in arbitrary ways. So it is surprising that $X=Y$ is the only case where $Z=(X+Y)/2$ is uniform on $[0,1]$. Just a follow up question: In general, does the distribution of $Z$ (may not be uniform) uniquely determine the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ (with the marginals restricted to uniform $[0,1]$)? Is there any reference for such results? Thank you.

Comment: @Yi-HsuanLin No, that is not true.  This result is special and very interesting. Thanks for posting this question.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I see. The general question I am thinking now is if the distributions of $X$, $Y$, and $X+Y$ determine the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$. So the answer is no in general. But I couldn't come up with a counter example. I do not know if this type of questions has been studied in the fields of probability theory or statistics. If you happen to see any reference, please let me know. Thank you.